# How to edit First Page Number in excel via R RDCOMClient?

Tags: r, rdcomclient

I am trying to edit the First Page Number in Page Setup in Excel Via R

```
library(RDCOMClient)
xlApp <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")
xlApp[["Visible"]] <- TRUE
xlBook <- xlApp[["Workbooks"]]$Add()
xlSheet <- xlBook[["Worksheets"]]$Item(1)
xlSheet$PageSetup()$FirstPageNumber() <- 1
```

Error in xlSheet$PageSetup()$FirstPageNumber() <- 1 : 
  invalid (NULL) left side of assignment

Answer (score 0):

```
x <- xlSheet[["PageSetup"]]
x[["FirstPageNumber"]] <- 1
```